# Value observing in iOS

Tags: ios, uibutton, key-value-observing

I have a MorphView.h file in which it tracks the position of the finger on the MorphView object.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MorphView : UIButton

@property (nonatomic) float morphX;
@property (nonatomic) float morphY;

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event ;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

@end
```

I want to "observe" morphX  of button from my Main view controller. I read up on key value observing and did this.

In init of ViewController.m

```
    MorphView* morphPadBtn = [MorphView buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];     
    [morphPadBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(morphPressedDown:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    UIImage *buttonbkImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonback"];
    [morphPadBtn setBackgroundImage:buttonbkImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [morphPadBtn setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:NO];
    morphPadBtn.frame = CGRectMake(300, 200, 300, 300.0);
    [self.view addSubview:morphPadBtn];        
    [morphPadBtn addObserver:morphPadBtn forKeyPath:@"morphX" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
```

and also did the required function for observing.

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"morphX"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Success in observation!"); 
    }
}
```

However, I don't see "Success in observation" being printed. Am I doing this wrong? All I want is to track my morphX value from my main view controller.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added an observer for the key path of `morphX`, not `MorphView.morphX`. Change the observer to compare against the correct path.

```
if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"morphX"])
```

If you want to ensure this is coming from a specific object then compare the `object` parameter against some instance variable maintaining a reference to the object.

Also, you are passing the wrong observer to `addObserver...`. It should be:

```
[morphPadBtn addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"morphX" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
```

The observer needs to be the class that implements the `observeValueForKeyPath:...` method.

Comment: Hi, sorry I actually started with morphX there and changed it due to it not working. When MorphView.morphX is changed to morphX is still doesn't work. Edited.

Comment: Hmm it still doesn't work. Do I have to specifically do anything in the setter value in MorphView? Currently I'm just doing _morphX = location.x; in touchesBegan

Comment: You have to assign the property, not the ivar.

Comment: Ah, changing _morphX to self.morphX worked! I always thought it was the same. Thanks!